# I want to select same option from drop list multiple data using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to select same option from drop list in multiple data using javascript. please help. Screenshot attached for refference

[image]

Comment: Do you want to select the option from drop down?? "Disapproval reason"

Comment: I don't understand your question, please consider to add more description

Comment: Flagged as **very low quality**.

Comment: Actually, I want just select "others" option in a website. There is several data, aprrox 50 per page. I use shif+ctrl+K (for firefox) to select checkbox all at at a time using javascript code. Now I want select same value(like "Others") at time using java script

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to know.
"How to change selected value of multiple select dropdowns using js/jquery"

Here is a sample code.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="selectv3">Select Value 2 on all</button>
<br>
<br>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="select2">
  <option value="value1" selected>Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
<br>
<select id="select4">
  <option value="none"></option> 
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<br>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#selectv3").click(function() {
        jQuery("select").val("value2");
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, I want just select "others" option in a website. There is several data, aprrox 50 per page. I use shif+ctrl+K (for firefox) to select checkbox all at at a time using javascript code. Now I want select same value(like "Others") at time using java script code.